# Georgia (USA) data issues in OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, united-states

There is an annoying green background feature displayed in the Georgia, USA OpenStreetMap data that doesn't appear in other adjacent states. See:

http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/161957#map=8/33.246/-83.790

The green background is rather overwhelming and obscures other critical map data for my needs. Has anyone encountered this and found a solution to turning off the "green layer"?

Comment: it looks like Georgia has more woods/forrest than the other states - or may be it's peach trees?

Comment: Funny how the forest stops exactly at the state line?

Comment: that probably means it was imported from a State database.

Comment: Perhaps there is a specific Style directive (I am using OSM Bright on my local server) I can use to turn it off?

Comment: Looks to me like the forest layer has been incorrectly placed on another feature layer for Georgia. When I turn off "forest" features in Mapnik, the green background remains. I will try investigating the shapefiles in QGIS to get more hints.

Comment: it is not tagged as forest, but `natural=wood`. You can test it using the JOSM editor.

Comment: It's probably because that landuse is imported for this state and not for the surrounding states. You see the same in Pennsylvania

Comment: See this [similar question on help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/42187/why-do-new-jersey-and-georgia-render-mostly-green).

Comment: AndreJ, correct it is tagged as wood. I was able to remove the line:

[type='wood']  { polygon-fill: @wooded; }

from the base.mss file in my OSMBright style, rebuild, delete the tile cache and indeed the green background is removed. Unfortunately for Georgia it also removes the fill for national forest lands.